Insert block of text at beginning of a file
I've seen a number of posts about injecting single lines at the beginning of a file. However, I haven't really any that answer to injecting a block of text into the beginning of an existing file. While I have a solution:
install -bDm 0660 -o root -g root <(
    echo "# Set external URL"
    printf "external_url = '%s'\n\n" "${EXTERNAL_URL}"
    cat <PATH_TO_EXISTING_FILE>
  ) <PATH_TO_EXISTING_FILE>

This feels really ugly. So, I was wondering if there was something less kludgey (and that didn't rely on encapsulating python/perl/etc. within a bash script).
Note: I had ultimately settled on this method because when you try something more like:
(
  echo "# Set external URL"
  printf "external_url = '%s'\n\n" "${EXTERNAL_URL}"
  cat <PATH_TO_EXISTING_FILE>
) <PATH_TO_EXISTING_FILE>

You get an error like cat: <PATH_TO_EXISTING_FILE>: input file is output file.

The particular context of an install command requires that the combined result be available via a file name, which in your example you provide via process substitution.  Is this essential for you?  Also, do you require that everything be accomplished via a single command?

Side note, the -D option to your example install command is pointless, because you're already assuming that the destination path designates an existing file.

I would solve this with an in-place sed command:
sed -i -e "1i # Set external URL\nexternal_url = '${EXTERNAL_URL}'\n\n" <PATH_TO_EXISTING_FILE>

Explanation:

-i means edit the file in place
-e to provide the expression on the command line
1i <contents> says insert <contents> at the first line
and \n gets replaced by a newline by sed itself, not the shell, so this should work in any shell.


sed -i could change PATH_TO_EXISTING_FILEs permissions, e.g. see https://stackoverflow.com/q/37163619/1745001.


However, I haven't really any that answer to injecting a block of text into the beginning of an existing file.

You cannot add data to a file without rewriting the tail of the file, starting at the (first) insertion point.  If you're inserting at the beginning then that means rewriting the entire file.  If you're doing it via shell commands then you lack the control to overwrite only part of the file, so any addition other than at the end requires overwriting the entire file.
Sometimes simpler is better, and the simplest way to do this would involve multiple commands and a regular temporary file.  For example:
tempfile=$(mktemp)

echo "# Set external URL" > "$tempfile"
printf "external_url = '%s'\n\n" "${EXTERNAL_URL}" >> "$tempfile"
cat <PATH_TO_EXISTING_FILE> >> "$tempfile"

# Option 1 (Requires more privilege)
chown --reference=<PATH_TO_EXISTING_FILE> "$tempfile"
chmod --reference=<PATH_TO_EXISTING_FILE> "$tempfile"
mv "$tempfile" <PATH_TO_EXISTING_FILE>

# Option 2 (Requires less privilege)
cat "$tempfile" > <PATH_TO_EXISTING_FILE>
rm "$tempfile"

Option 1 does rely on the GNU Coreutils versions of chown and chmod, but that's a non-essential detail. It also requires

the script is executed by the owner of the file or by a privileged user
the group of the target file is among the groups of the user executing the script, or the executing user is privileged
the user has permission to write to the directory of the file

Option 2 requires only permission to write to the target file, but it is a bit less safe as it may interfere with other processes that already have the target file open.  It also requires a separate cleanup of the temp file, as shown.
Although that's not as compact as some alternatives, I daresay it's extremely clear as to what it's doing and how, and it's easy to expand, adapt, maintain, and modify.

Usually only root can use chown. Instead you could copy the original file to a temporary, make the changes there, then overwrite the original file.

@Barmar, anyone can chown a file that they already own to themselves, and when possible, it is safer to replace a file that other processes might be using than to modify it in place.  Plus, the OP's example assumes that it is being executed by a privileged user.  Nevertheless, I have described a second variant that does as you describe, plus added some comments about the privileges required for each option.

If they already own it, why would they need to chown it to themselves?

small performance improvement with just one open/write/close operation on $tempfile - { echo ... ; printf ... ; cat ... ; } > "$tempfile"

@Barmar, so that the same code that serves root in the general case will also serve unprivileged users in the case of files that they own (in directories they can modify).

I considered that, @markp-fuso, and decided to go instead with the simpler (IMO) alternative presented.  I acknowledge that the version presented is a bit more costly, but clarity and simplicity are the focus.  There are of course all manner of variations with characteristics that differ in one way or another.

Assuming you want to keep the original permissions and ownership of PATH_TO_EXISTING_FILE then on any system that has bash you could do:
#!/usr/bin/env bash

tmp=$(mktemp) && 
trap 'rm -f "$tmp"; exit' EXIT &&
{
    echo "# Set external URL" &&
    printf "external_url = '%s'\n\n" "$EXTERNAL_URL" &&
    cat PATH_TO_EXISTING_FILE
} > "$tmp" &&
cat "$tmp" > PATH_TO_EXISTING_FILE &&
rm -f "$tmp"

I'm using cat "$tmp" > PATH_TO_EXISTING_FILE instead of mv "$tmp" PATH_TO_EXISTING_FILE or similar to avoid changing any of PATH_TO_EXISTING_FILEs permissions or ownership.
You don't actually need the && rm -f "$tmp" at the end if you have the trap I show and this code is run from a script.
If you're feeling brave and are interested in truly "injecting a block of text into the beginning of an existing file" then Remove first N lines of a file in place in unix command line might (or might not) give you a starting point.
